# Can you beat Mangar without the special trick? (early game minor spoiler)

Tags: the-bards-tale-4-barrows-deep

Fairly early on in The Bard's Tale IV: Barrows' Deep, you get into a boss-fight style brawl with Mangar.

He has a *lot* of HP, armour and spell power, but

> a guest character, Aduin, has a special banishment spell that needs five turns to charge up, allowing him to nuke Mangar if you just survive that long, at the cost of burning up his capacity for magic permanently.

However, during my recent playthrough I was doing surprisingly well against Mangar conventionally -- a 2H fighter cracked his armour down to zero, two spellcasters that could smack his Mental defenses every time he tried to meditate to recover HP, and AoE attacks to keep the totem spam manageabl -- and I can't help but feeling that it might have been possible to win that fight *without* resorting to the spoiled gimmick.

Is that in fact possible, and does it change the outcome WRT

> Aduin

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just grinded and achieved it earlier. I had two mages and my bard with my rogue to take arrows and let em fly then I just stun-locked him and drained his mana. Mental attacks so I never had to do anything but charge up my mages. Tough news though, it does nothing, everything stays the same.

Comment: I figured as much because it's a pretty big plot point. Thanks for testing it out!